# Member in group is failing triggers constant (Re-)joining group in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

My application is reading a topic from kafka and after enriching it it saves it to another topic. The `StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG` is configured to `8`. I have two brokers and 12 partitions.

```
Topic: enriched-request PartitionCount: 12  ReplicationFactor: 2    Configs: min.insync.replicas=1,flush.ms=86400000,segment.bytes=1073741824,flush.messages=1073741824,max.message.bytes=1000000,index.interval.bytes=4096,unclean.leader.election.enable=false,retention.bytes=-1,delete.retention.ms=259200000,segment.ms=604800000,segment.index.bytes=10485760
    Topic: enriched-request Partition: 0    Leader: 7   Replicas: 7,8   Isr: 7,8
    Topic: enriched-request Partition: 1    Leader: 8   Replicas: 8,7   Isr: 7,8
    Topic: enriched-request Partition: 2    Leader: 7   Replicas: 7,8   Isr: 7,8
    Topic: enriched-request Partition: 3    Leader: 8   Replicas: 8,7   Isr: 7,8
    Topic: enriched-request Partition: 4    Leader: 7   Replicas: 7,8   Isr: 7,8
    Topic: enriched-request Partition: 5    Leader: 8   Replicas: 8,7   Isr: 7,8
    Topic: enriched-request Partition: 6    Leader: 7   Replicas: 7,8   Isr: 7,8
    Topic: enriched-request Partition: 7    Leader: 8   Replicas: 8,7   Isr: 7,8
    Topic: enriched-request Partition: 8    Leader: 7   Replicas: 7,8   Isr: 7,8
    Topic: enriched-request Partition: 9    Leader: 8   Replicas: 8,7   Isr: 7,8
    Topic: enriched-request Partition: 10   Leader: 7   Replicas: 7,8   Isr: 7,8
    Topic: enriched-request Partition: 11   Leader: 8   Replicas: 8,7   Isr: 7,8
```

Since two weeks now in my testing environment I get the log message:
`INFO AbstractCoordinator:336 - [Consumer clientId=my-enrichments-client-StreamThread-4-consumer, groupId=my-enrichments] (Re-)joining group` and this I get for all 8 threads. Every 5 minutes this is triggered and every time its a new set of 8 threads.

In my `kafka.log` I see:
`Member my-enrichments-client-StreamThread-4-consumer-6409090a-9d06-4bc0-8dd0-cd4c8bd28d71 in group my-enrichments has failed, removing it from the group (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)` again for all 8 threads. The same as above here, every 5 minutes these are new sets of 8 threads that it is removing.

Only one application is running in my test environment. I tried waiting for 15-20 minutes to redeploy, but I keep getting the same error. Anyone has any idea how I can solve it without having to change the `StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG` or `StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG`?

**Consumer configuration**

```
final Properties streamsConfiguration = new Properties();
streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "my-enrichments");
streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "my-enrichments-client");
streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, my bootstrap sersvers);
streamsConfiguration.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG, WallclockTimestampExtractor.class.getName());
streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG, 8);
streamsConfiguration.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "snappy");
```

If it helps anything it started to happen a week or so after I increased the number of threads from `3` to `8`. I don't know if it's related to it.

Comment: Can you share the configuration of your consumers?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous I added the configuration

Comment: What is your config for `max.poll.interval.ms`?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous the default which is probably `300000`

Answer (score 1):

Since I couldn't find an answer, I tried the following:

1. Describe the group. `bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server my-kafka-server:9092 --describe --group my-enrichments`. With this I got the warning `Warning: Consumer group 'my-enrichments' is rebalancing.`
2. Deleting it. `bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server my-kafka-server:9092 --delete --group my-enrichments` this caused the error:

```
Error: Deletion of some consumer groups failed:
* Group 'my-enrichments' could not be deleted due to: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.GroupNotEmptyException: The group is not empty.
```

3. Restarting the broker fixed the problem.